# 3 Monitors amd r9 270x 3gb

Tags: windows, windows-10, display

I have an pc with an r9 270x 3gb in it. And im trying to put 3 monitors but it wont work. I have 2 dvi ports used and 1 hdmi with an vga to hdmi converter. But it wont work

Comment: Do any of the monitors work? Is it just an issue with the VGA/HDMI one?

Comment: You can't have a VGA - HDMI converter, I presume you mean HDMI - VGA. Please edit & clarify. Chances are the card can only do 'any two from three' - they're cheaper that way. You'd have to check the manufacturer's details for that specific card model.

Comment: How many HDMI and DisplayPort ports does your card have?